# Global (systemwide) queue object, shared across multiple processes

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, queue, ipc

Is there a simple way to share a queue object across multiple processes (systemwide) in the same way to share global Mutex or Semaphore objects? the needed scenario is that there is a single process managing multiple worker processes, the main process will queue work items, and workers will get their work items from this global queue object.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing ?

Comment: Many thanks @ValentinP. I was looking for a simpler solution, this needs some  external components to be installed.